# Multi processing can't pickle in cython

Tags: python, c, cython

Since my current project is big, I am going to provide the portion of the code that I believe have the problem and is reproducible.

**What am I trying to do?** A: I am trying to develop a file system mini-filter driver. I would like to develop the:

- Kernel mode using pure C/WDK
- User mode made of a C program that directly interacts with the kernel mode. I also have a cython/.pyd module which then is included in my C program that interacts with kernel.

In summary, when the kernel want the user mode to do something, the kernel sends an signal to the usermode/C program, and the C program then forwards the request to the cython module. Why am I using cython you may ask? A: Because I would to code certain functionalities of the driver in python that doesn't require performance and can be easily developed in python. I understand that this may have never been done by someone else, but this could be a great experiment :)

**CyModule.pyx**

```
class doMath(Process):
    def __init__(self, daemon=True):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = daemon

    def run(self):
        print("What up?")

cdef public void mainCode():
    mathematicalStuff = doMath()
    mathematicalStuff.start()
```

**CyModule.pxd**

```
cdef public void mainCode()
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc

ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        "CyModule",
        sources=["CyModule.pyx", ],#"Updater.pyx",

    ),
]
setup(
    name="modules",
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules),
    include_dirs=[
                ".",
                get_python_inc(),
                ],
    compiler_directives={'language_level': 3, "unraisable_tracebacks": True}
)
```

Finally, I compile my setup.py using `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, this will generate a CyModule.h file which can be used with external C program. Now, If I open a python console, and do the following, the program works perfectly fine.

```
>>> import CyModule
>>> mathematicalStuff = CyModule.doMath()
>>> mathematicalStuff.start()
>>> What up?
```

As you can see `What up?` is printed.

Now, rather than using python console app, I would like to use a pure C program that call `mainCode` from my CyModule.pyd which then call `doMath()`.

**run.c**

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "CyModule.h"

//gcc -o run.exe run.c CyModule.c -IC:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -LC:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs -lpython39
int main(){
    printf("current PID %d\n", getpid());
    PyImport_AppendInittab("mainCode", PyInit_CyModule);
    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject *sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
    PyObject *path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");
    PyList_Append(path, PyUnicode_FromString("."));
    PyList_Append(path, PyUnicode_FromString("C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/python39/"));


    /* 1st: Import the module */
    PyObject* ModuleString = PyUnicode_FromString((char*) "CyModule");
    if (!ModuleString) {
        PyErr_Print();
        printf("Error formating python script\n");
    }

    PyObject* Module = PyImport_Import(ModuleString);
    if (!Module) {
        PyErr_Print();
        printf("Error importing python script\n");
    }


    /* 2nd: Getting reference to the function */
    PyObject* Function = PyObject_GetAttrString(Module, (char*)"mainCode");
    if (!Function) {
        PyErr_Print();
        printf("Pass valid argument to mainCode()\n");
    }

    if(PyImport_ImportModule("mainCode") == NULL){
        printf("Failed to import mainCode\n");
    }
    __pyx_f_13commonmodules_mainCode();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I then compile my C program using:

```
gcc -o run.exe run.c CyModule.c -IC:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -LC:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs -lpython39
```

This compiles the program just fine, but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
current PID 12300
Exception ignored in: 'CyModule.mainCode'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'CyModule.doMath'>: it's not the same object as commonmodules.doMath
```

Does anyone know, how do I call mainCode in my run.c program where the doMath could be pickled by the multiprocessing?

I tried some suggestion from the internet, such as:

```
def PickleDoMath():
    mathematicalStuff = doMath()
    mathematicalStuff.start()

cdef public void mainCode():
    PickleDoMath()
```

This didn't work either.